# RichFaces Sorting Icon

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I am migrating a richfaces 3.x application to 4.x, on a datatable i need to add sorting functionality which is not built in, i have added the sorting functionality but i need to place icons for the sorting functionality, how do i pick icons from richfaces components ui jar? should i place new icons inside the project and then access it.

```
  <rich:dataTable id="showsEventsTable">

     <rich:column sortable="true" selfSorted="true" 
                    sortBy="#{show.name}" sortorder="SortOrder.ascending" sortOrder="#{sortingBean.showNameOrder}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <a4j:commandLink value="Show Name" render="showsEventsTable" action="#{sortingBean.sortByShowName()}"
                        styleClass="sortingColumn" status="waitStatus">
                          <span styleClass="#{sortingBean.sortOrder}"/>
                            <h:graphicImage value="??(what should go here if am accessing richfaces components jar)" library="org.richfaces"/>
                       </a4j:commandLink>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{show.name}" />
                </rich:column>

   </rich:dataTable>
```

In the css file

```
    .ascending{
       background-image: url("imgpath");
     } 

  .descending{
     background-image: url("imgpath");
  } 

  .unsorted{
     background-image: url("imgpath");
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application was migrated to RichFaces 4.5, then you don't need accessing to sorting icons - its appear automatically, when sorting is added.

If application was migrated to previous version of RichFaces 4.x, then simple add 3 sorting icons (from RichFaces 3 or RichFaces 4 jar) in your application and use it.

**UPDATE**

Following is example have to use sorting icons:

```
<rich:column id="date" sortBy="#{rs.changeDate}" sortOrder="descending">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:commandLink value="#{msg.entryDate}" styleClass="tableColumnHeader">
            <rich:componentControl target="noteTable" operation="sort">
                <f:param name="column" value="date" />
                <f:param value="" />
                <f:param name="reset" value="true" />
            </rich:componentControl>
            <h:graphicImage value="/images/sort/sort_asc.gif"
                style="border: 0px; vertical-align: middle;"
                rendered="#{chNotesAction.list.order == 'changeDate ASC'}" />
            <h:graphicImage value="/images/sort/sort_des.gif"
                style="border: 0px; vertical-align: middle;"
                rendered="#{chNotesAction.list.order == 'changeDate DESC'}" />
            <h:graphicImage value="/images/sort/sort_uns.gif"
                style="border: 0px; vertical-align: middle;"
                rendered="#{chNotesAction.list.order != 'changeDate ASC'
                    and chNotesAction.list.order != 'changeDate DESC'}" />
        </h:commandLink>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{rs.changeDate}">
        <f:convertDateTime timeZone="#{referenceData.timezone}" pattern="MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm" />
    </h:outputText>
</rich:column>
```

You can use 1 graphicImage with EL for `value` attribute like `order eq 'ASC' ? sort_acs.gif : (order eq 'DESC' ? sort_desc.gif : sort_unc.gif)`

Comment: My application is not migrated to 4.5, ok i will add the icons to the application and try to use them. thanks.

Comment: i added a <span styleClass ="#{bean.sortOrder}"/> and in the css file  i have three different classes for three images with the value coming from bean.sortOrder but still not working.

Comment: your answer is working absolutely fine, thanks for your timely help.